# How to simulate feature changes in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, simulation

**Situation**
I trained a machine learning model to predict whether a person will pay back their loan or not. There are about 150 features and 35,000 people in the dataset. Each person represents one row.

**Goal**
Now, I want to give personal recommendations to a person in the dataset, so that this person has a smaller risk of loan default. Out of the 150 features, 10 are influenceable in the short-term by the person. For example, a short-term influenceable feature is "$ spent on clothes per year". So I could take the row from the dataset for this person, enter a different value for this feature, and see how the probability of loan default changes.

**Issues**
One, correlation versus causation could be an issue.
Two, if my model is a tree-based one, there might be hard cuts in the decision function. For example, the probability of default might be 20% for that person, but if I change the feature from $1000 to 1001 spent on clothes per year, the probability of default might jump to 60%, which is obviously not realistic.

**Question**
Is this something that has been done in research before? I could not find any papers that apply this methodology.
If yes, how should I handle the issues mentioned above?

Comment: SHAP (Tree Explainer) could help.  https://slundberg.github.io/shap/notebooks/NHANES%20I%20Survival%20Model.html

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you meant correlation versus causation not correlation again!  But with that, all we really are dealing with are correlations and that is fine for prediction, so that is a problem in any method you will choose to use.
2. With tree models the splits can cause issues with a simulation strategy you are talking about, namely holding everything else the same and changing one thing slightly.  If the simulation is your ultimate goal you may get more bang for your buck with linear models which sound like they may give you more theoretically sound results, although probably at the cost of some prediction accuracy.  One of the strength of trees is that they are handling complex interactions nicely, so although you are changing one unit slightly in the simulation, in the real world that one unit may really move with other things which is why the tree is splitting where it splits.

In terms of simulation research, if you turn to linear models then that is a very well researched and documented field but for you it really is as simple as just changing the variable and getting a different output.  If you want to get 'in the trenches' with simulation and stats then bayesian models are the way to go.

Comment: Would you have a starting point where to start searching for research, which documents variable changes in linear models?